# I'm trying to skip tokens in gplex (a flex/lex port) and using yylex() is causing a stack overflow. Is there a better way to skip?

Tags: c#, lex

So right now in my lexer I'm trying to skip certain tokens like comments and whitespace, except I need to add them to my "skipped list", rather than hiding them altogether.

In my Scanner frame I have

```
public int Skip(int sym) {
    Token t = _InitToken();
    t.SymbolId=sym;
    t.Line = Current.Line;
    t.Column =Current.Column;
    t.Position=Current.Position;
    t.Value = yytext;
    t.Skipped = null;
    _skipped.Add(t);
    return yylex();
}
```

keep in mind this is c# but the interface isn't much different than the C one in lex/flex

I then use this function above in my scanner like so:

```
"/*"    { if(!_TryReadUntilBlockEnd("*/")) return -1; return Skip(478); }
\/\/[^\n]*  { return Skip(477); }
```

where `477` is my symbol id (the lex file is generated hence the lack of constants)

All `_TryReadUntilBlockEnd("*/")` does is read until it finds a trailing */, consuming it. It's a well tested method and can be ignored for the purposes of this question, except as explanation for how i match the end of a comment. This takes over the underlying input from gplex and handles advancing the underlying input stream itself (like `fget()` or whatever in C i forget). Basically it's neutral here other than reading the entire comment. `Skip(478)` is the relevant bit, not this.

It works fine in many cases. The only problem is I'm using it in a recursive descent parser that's parsing C#, and so the stack gets heavy, and when i have a huge stream of line comments it stack overflows.

I can solve it by finding some way to run a match without invoking a lex action again instead of calling `yylex()` if it's possible - that way i can rewrite it to be iterative, but i have no idea how, and what I've seen from the generated code suggests it's not possible.

The other way I can solve it - and this is my preferred way - is to match multiple C# line comments in one match. That way I only recurse once.

But this is multiline match expression which is disabled by default i think?

How do i enable multiline matching in either flex, lex or *gplex? Or is there another solution to the above problem? *gplex 1.2.2 preferred but it's completely undocumented

I'll take anything at this point. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you not replace `return Skip(478);` with just `Skip(478);` and remove the recursive call to `yylex()` from the `Skip` function.  If you don't return, the lexer will continue from where it left off, consuming input without adding recursive calls.  Similarly, drop the `return` from `return Skip(477);`.  You might decide that `Skip` becomes a function returning `void`.

Comment: Are you also doing a recursive call to yylex in your whitespace rules? If not, why are you doing it here? If so, why do you feel it to be necessary?

Comment: I didn't know that. =) I just started using this tool last week, and have been developing a parser generator at the same time, so my knowledge is woeful right now. I gleaned what i could from man pages and such

Comment: I tested your suggestions Jonathan and rici. This worked and sped up my parse. Thank you both so much.

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't have been calling yylex() at all. Thanks Jonathan and rici in the comments.